# Searching a particular word in a matrix of characters

Tags: c, search, matrix

I was trying to search for a particular word in a matrix of characters through **C** but was unable to come to a fixed solution.

For ex:
Suppose I have to search for the word **INTELLIGENT** in a matrix of characters (3*9)
(Once you have picked a character from the matrix to form a sentence, you cannot pick it again to form the same sentence.There is a path from any cell to all its neighboring cells. A neighbor may share an edge or a corner.)

```
IIIINN.LI  
....TTEGL  
.....NELI
```

Output: YES (the word INTELLIGENT can be found)
Can anybody please give a solution to the above problem !!!!

Comment: Yes.. I was trying to do it for the 10 hours but was unable to think a particular solution !! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char Matrix[3][9] = {
    { 'I','I','I','I','N','N','.','L','I'},
    { '.','.','.','.','T','T','E','G','L'},
    { '.','.','.','.',',','N','E','L','I'}
};
char Choice[3][9] = { { 0 }, { 0 }, { 0 } };
const char WORD[] = "INTELLIGENT";
const int  Len = sizeof(WORD)-1;
int Path[sizeof(WORD)-1] = { 0 };

char get(int row, int col){
    if(1 > col || col > 9) return '\0';
    if(1 > row || row > 3) return '\0';
    if(Choice[row-1][col-1] || Matrix[row-1][col-1] == '.')
        return '\0';
    else
        return Matrix[row-1][col-1];
}

#define toLoc(r, c) (r)*10+(c)
#define getRow(L) L/10
#define getCol(L) L%10

int search(int loc, int level){
    int r,c,x,y;
    char ch;
    if(level == Len) return 1;//find it
    r = getRow(loc);
    c = getCol(loc);
    ch = get(r,c);
    if(ch == 0 || ch != WORD[level]) return 0;
    Path[level]=toLoc(r,c);
    Choice[r-1][c-1] = 'v';//marking
    for(x=-1;x<=1;++x){
        for(y=-1;y<=1;++y){
            if(search(toLoc(r+y,c+x), level + 1)) return 1;
        }
    }
    Choice[r-1][c-1] = '\0';//reset
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    int r,c,i;
    for(r=1;r<=3;++r){
        for(c=1;c<=9;++c){
            if(search(toLoc(r,c), 0)){
                printf("YES\nPath:");
                for(i=0;i<Len;++i){
                    printf("(%d,%d)", getRow(Path[i]), getCol(Path[i]));
                }
                printf("\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("NO\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code... But can you please describe it so that it would be easier to understand...

Comment: @Snehasish - You do not know which part?

Comment: the search function..!! how exactly is the search being performed..?? and what is the concept behind it....??

Comment: @Snehasish - The concept is brute. While searching to see if that meets the requirements for the first time around then that from the first location of the 3 * 9.

Comment: I modified ur code to search for the word INTELLIGENT in the array of 1 * 10
{ 'I','N','T','E','L','L','I','G','E', 'N', 'T'}
I changed the size of the choice array as well as the upper limits in get(), also in main function i changed the limits but the output was ...
NO
Can u please tell what more modifications I hv to make.

Comment: @Snehasish - Please see and try the newly added answer. It's a matter of how to deal with coordinate a nutshell.

Answer (score 1):

Use a depth first search.

You can do this using a recursive algorthm. Find all the (unused) places containing the first letter then see if it is possible to find the rest of the word on the remaining board by starting from one of the adjacent squares.

Comment: Sorry to say... but I am just a newbie and I am unable to understand what are you saying....

Comment: @Snehasish: It seems a rather difficult question to give a newbie for homework. Have you been taught about depth first search or recursion in class yet?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean.....  Though it seems simpler to what you currently have been offered, so I may have misunderstood the question.

I use Numpy to reshape an arbitrary array into a single
list of letters, then we create a mask of the search term and
a copy of the input list.
I tick off each letter to search for while updating the mask.

```py
import numpy as np
import copy

def findInArray(I,Word):
    M=[list(x) for x in I]

    M=list(np.ravel(M))

    print "Letters to start: %s"%"".join(M)

    Mask=[False]*len(Word)

    T = copy.copy(M)

    for n,v in enumerate(Word):
        try:
            p=T.index(v)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            T[p]=''
            Mask[n]=True

    print "Letters left over: %s"%"".join(T)            
    if all(Mask):print "Found %s"%Word
    else:print "%s not Found"%Word

    print "\n"

    return all(Mask)


I=["IIIINN.LI","....TTEGL",".....NELI"]

findInArray(I,"INTEL")
findInArray(I,"INTELLIGENT")
findInArray(I,"INTELLIGENCE")
```

***Example output***

*Letters to start: IIIINN.LI....TTEGL.....NELI

Letters left over: IIIN.I....TGL.....NELI

Found INTEL*

Letters to start: IIIINN.LI....TTEGL.....NELI
Letters left over: II.I.........NLI
Found INTELLIGENT

Letters to start: IIIINN.LI....TTEGL.....NELI
Letters left over: II.I....T.....NLI
INTELLIGENCE not Found

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROW 1
#define COL 11

char Matrix[ROW][COL] = { { 'I','N','T','E','L','L','I','G','E', 'N', 'T'} };
char Choice[ROW][COL] = { { 0 } };
const char WORD[] = "INTELLIGENT";
const int  Len = sizeof(WORD)-1;
int Path[sizeof(WORD)-1] = { 0 };

char get(int row, int col){
    if(1 > col || col > COL) return '\0';
    if(1 > row || row > ROW) return '\0';
    if(Choice[row-1][col-1] || Matrix[row-1][col-1] == '.')
        return '\0';
    else
        return Matrix[row-1][col-1];
}

#define toLoc(r, c) (r)*16+(c)
#define getRow(L) L/16
#define getCol(L) L%16

int search(int loc, int level){
    int r,c,x,y;
    char ch;
    if(level == Len) return 1;//find it
    r = getRow(loc);
    c = getCol(loc);
    ch = get(r,c);
    if(ch == 0 || ch != WORD[level]) return 0;
    Path[level]=toLoc(r,c);
    Choice[r-1][c-1] = 'v';//marking
    for(x=-1;x<=1;++x){
        for(y=-1;y<=1;++y){
            if(search(toLoc(r+y,c+x), level + 1)) return 1;
        }
    }
    Choice[r-1][c-1] = '\0';//reset
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    int r,c,i;
    for(r=1;r<=ROW;++r){
        for(c=1;c<=COL;++c){
            if(search(toLoc(r,c), 0)){
                printf("YES\nPath:");
                for(i=0;i<Len;++i){
                    printf("(%d,%d)", getRow(Path[i]), getCol(Path[i]));
                }
                printf("\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("NO\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Snehasish - first version int loc is RC = R*10 + C(E.g.(2,8)->28). second version COLUMN range 1-11 , can't be expressed　by base 10. OK so say 16, even 256, even if only 11 or more.