# Python: Find a word in a matrix of characters

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to create a word game that involves finding words in a matrix of 5x5 characters, like so:

```
[['a', 'a', 'u', 'r', 'a'],
 ['m', 'v', 'g', 'n', 'x'],
 ['a', 'q', 'h', 'y', 'o'],
 ['p', 'r', 'h', 'l', 'h'],
 ['v', 'h', 'y', 'o', 'j']]
```

which I have represented as a list of lists. "xylon" should be found but not "nylon" since this reuses the 'n'. I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647950/searching-a-particular-word-in-a-matrix-of-characters) but I do not know C.

My current solution involves creating a dictionary for each letter in the word, consisting of a list of tuples of its location on the board like so: {'letter':[(row,column),(row,column)]}. Then, for each letter in the word, I check if each of its locations on the board are compatible with the locations of the previous letter. If it is, I add that location to a new *path dictionary*.

This fails though for repeating letters and other cases like "nylon" which does return True. It is already rather bulky and confusing and I should probably just start over. Is there a more succinct solution I can employ?
Edits:

To clarify: A word is "in" the grid if there exists a path connecting each letter in the word in the grid. Up, down, left, right, and diagonals are allowed. 'x' is adjacent to 'y', which is adjacent to 'l', and so on. The path needs to have no particular shape as long as each letter is adjacent and no specific letter on the board is used twice. A word *can* have repeating letters, so "pama" would be allowed because there are multiple 'a's that can be used.

@MSW is correct, the game is [boggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boggle), though I am finding this out for the first time!

Comment: Clarification would it be I type a word like MAP, and then it checks if that is in the grid?

Comment: you do write a small function that makes sure the `count` of each letter in the guessed word in 1. if yes return `True`, else `False`

Comment: What does it mean for a word to be "in" the grid? It can't see the logic of saying "xylon" is.

Comment: @JohnColeman 'x' and 'n' are in the same row for xylon

Comment: @helloV which deepens the mystery. There isn't a word-search *path* that would give "xylon". I can see well enough that all the letters are in the grid, but the grid-structure itself seems irrelevant.

Comment: @JohnColeman, you find the first letter of the word, then the next letter must be in one of the 8 positions surrounding it

Comment: To clarify: A word is "in" the grid if there exists a path connecting each letter in the word in the grid. Up, down, left, right, and diagonals are allowed. 'x' is adjacent to 'y', which is adjacent to 'l', and so on. @AndrewMairose is correct.

Comment: I think the OP is describing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boggle

Comment: [(1,4),(2,3),(3,3),(2,4),(1,3)] is xylon. it is in the grid.

Comment: Got it -- I was thinking about the sort of word searches where you were looking for rows, columns, diagonals, but this is admitting more snake-like paths.

Comment: some sort of back-tracking algorithm should work

Comment: Should the script (1) generate matrices given a list of words, (2) find solutions given a matrix and possible words or (3) finds solutions given a matrix and then an English dictionary or so?

Comment: @JonasLindeløv, only (2) is necessary (though (1) would certainly be very interesting). I have a find_all function for (3) assuming I can check whether any particular word works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check for word membership, your starting point of a dictionary mapping letters to positions is a good one:

```
letter_positions = {}
for (y, row) in enumerate(board):
    for (x, letter) in enumerate(row):
         letter_positions.setdefault(letter, []).append((x, y))
```

From there, your function should keep track of which letters have already been used to make sure it doesn't duplicate them:

```
def move_valid(position, last_position):
    if last_position is None:
        return True
    return (
        abs(position[0] - last_position[0]) <= 1 and
        abs(position[1] - last_position[1]) <= 1
    )

def find_word(word, used=None):
    if word == "":
        return []
    if used is None:
        used = []
    letter, rest = word[:1], word[1:]
    for position in letter_positions.get(letter) or []:
        if position in used:
            continue
        if not move_valid(position, used and used[-1]):
            continue
        path = find_word(rest, used + [position])
        if path is not None:
            return [position] + path
    return None
```

And for example:

```
>>> find_word("xylon")
[(4, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (4, 2), (3, 1)]
>>> find_word("bad")
None
```

Now, note that the runtime here will be `O(not great)` because of the `position in used` (`used` is a list and will require an `O(N)` search for each letter position) and the `used + [position]` and `[position] + path` (each of which will result in an allocation + copy). In practice this will be ~`O(word length ^ 2)`, but could be improved to ~`O(word length)` with some more sensible data structures.

Comment: The only thing I had to change was `if last_position is None` to `if last_position == []`, since that is what is returned by `used and used[-1]` when used is an empty list. Sorry for the comment delay, I'm a beginner and it took me a couple of days to understand the intricacies of just this short piece of code.  I appreciate the help!