# How to search for a word in 2D list and create a tuple containing row number, column number, and direction?

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I have a file of random letters.I converted this file to a two-dimensional list.I need a function that searches for any word in that list and creates a tuple containing the row and column numbers and direction from which that word starts.

```
word="THIS"
file = open("harf_uzayi.txt", "r")
letter_space=[[str(n) for n in line] for line in file] 
for letter in word:
    for j,sublist in enumerate(letter_space):
        if letter in sublist:
```

I'm very confused after this part. can you help me?

By the way, file sample is:

```
IRUZHZKYGUHGCPPJGSTTNUBUYSFUBKKURMGRGPOGVCVPNFICOS
GKRHUYFGNZPGDTFBGSMCUUAJSELULLIUGRATBYYAOEIMJNSMGU
FHDLCFUKOKUNCYDVNLGIIFUMGVMRDINKOYTFDEOGPPVOEDUAGY
IFKZGBDCVTNCUCCETOATSUYUSYUGHLBJOHPOOBOLEPSPMTGBCB
TAEPRGNUOIUBSKBGFCSHZDUVLCIBMFGYKLVMYSZDSMPPAGIDVO
DKZKOMRUİCİGFYTCTPRISPLJILYSGGYYGSBFNPUJCFUCMGMYCF
LAERLKPEIDAPIYFKGCISERRGZPBCKCNBGMCGCVVDGBAFBUVSUG
IOJVKBSCGVNOHCEOGVOPORVEHILOVOIMSBODSISSLASONREUSA
GNEITNCTAJSBMGMGNJTEBUCGAGAGULTBKOJNOZIODLMOIBRTMC
HBETZJUCGRKSZPHVONOSCIOPOOYAUMJOICSYPYSDUOUCRIEKSO
TABUSHSPMAHKBBOIGUDRZLHMUPUGGÜKKIOCTIZNSGZCEÇIOGEC
DUSUINNNCKFUCNOJGNEOCCSGAIMIUEOIEFBUBETOCOODOLUETT
```

Sample output:

```
WORD      line number  column number   direction

THIS         4            20            West
```

Comment: Could you add your desired output for a particular word?

Comment: Could you post code in english, ie english variable names, it's very hard to read

Comment: I changed it , sorry @SayandipDutta

Comment: changed it,sorry @azro

Comment: I was talking about the variable names, I don't care about your text content. Also specify if you look to group of letter or letter, because you sublist split all chars so you don't have words anymore, please give an input example and the output you expect

Comment: I added something I hope this helps @azro

Comment: Can't see you word at the index you pointed ^^

Comment: you can see the word "this" in the fourth row and in the twentieth column from top to bottom @azro

Comment: You wrote '12' instead of '20', just understand that you look also top and bottom way^^

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Find a word in a matrix of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686957/python-find-a-word-in-a-matrix-of-characters)

Comment: sorry for that , I'm inexperienced to ask questions on this site so I make some mistakes. I need to look in all directions for the searched word @azro

Comment: Ok good luck so, I don't how to do this, maybe look to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686957/python-find-a-word-in-a-matrix-of-characters

Comment: I suggest you first try to find the word in the left-to-right direction which would be the easiest. After you get that working, then maybe how to search in the other 3 directions will be more obvious. BTW, you can create the 2D list in a simpler way: `letter_space = [list(line.strip()) for line in file]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regex`'s *named capturing groups* `(?P<name> )` and *alternation operator* `|`.

```
import re
with open("text.txt") as txt:
    words = "|".join(["SYUB", "TAJ", "THIS", "EDOT"])

    #   lines is a matrix
    lines = txt.readlines()
    pattern = re.compile(f"(?P<e>{words})|(?P<w>{words[::-1]})")
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        for word in pattern.finditer(line):
            print(word.group(0), i, word.span()[0], word.lastgroup)

    #   transpose lines and search again
    lines = [''.join(i) for i in zip(*lines)]
    pattern = re.compile(f"(?P<s>{words})|(?P<n>{words[::-1]})")
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        for word in pattern.finditer(line):
            print(word.group(0), word.span()[0], i , word.lastgroup)
```

output:

```
BUYS 0 22 w
TAJ  8  7 e
TODE 8 18 n
THIS 3 19 s
```

Comment: Should work in horizontal both ways and vertical both ways :/

Comment: @azro now works in both ways.

Comment: thanks for help. just one thing, i will use this as a function with one word .then should I compile too? I didn't understand the part you compile.

Comment: @mcora yes, because ```pattern``` reused for each ```line```. and it'd better if you provided all words once and called your function rather than calling for each word.

Comment: @mcora But if you can't because you are getting your words incrementally I think there is a better way to solve this.

Comment: in fact, my program takes words from a different text if I use it at the beginning, all the work will be done, thanks