# Finding locations of words as lists of coordinates in a grid of letters

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a grid of letters and a list of words, find the location of each word as a list of coordinates. Resulting list can be in any order, but coordinates for individual words must be given in order. Letters cannot be reused across words, and letters. Each given word is guaranteed to be in the grid. Consecutive letters of words are either down or to the right (i.e no reversed words or reversed sections of words, only down or to the right).

For example, given the following grid and set of words,

```
 [
    ['d', 'r', 'd', 'o', 'r', 's'],
    ['o', 'b', 'i', 'g', 'n', 'c'],
    ['g', 'f', 'n', 'm', 't', 'a'],
    ['x', 's', 'i', 'a', 'n', 't']
]

words1 = [ "dog", "dogma", "cat" ]
```

output the list of coordinates below:

```
findWords(grid, words)->
  [ [ (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5) ], # cat
    [ (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)], # dogma
    [ (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0) ], # dog
  ]
```

In this example, the "dog" in "dogma" cannot be used for the word "dog" since letters cannot be reused.

Comment: Just an intuition, but the restriction of "cannot use the same letter twice" smells like NP-Hard to me. (The intuition to me is the crossword problem). If this is the case, you can invoke backtracking once you tried a solution and found it's not feasible, with the basic solver you had using trie, but different words order. Does that make sense?

Comment: @amit So you're saying like it's a sudoku solver. You try out a combination, except instead of placing a single number, you're searching for an entire word. Keep a seen set to mark which letters have been used for quick look up. If you reach a combination of paths/seen characters that doesn't let you find all the words, back track until the last branching point, and keep trying for all combinations. The only issue I see with this is having to differentiate between different paths. This was a hard question tbh and i only had 20 minutes left for this question after answering two before :/

Comment: Well, this is just my intuition, I am not sure I am correct. I can tell you, that as an interviewer - I always have some followup to ask. Sometimes I don't even ask the interviewee to actually implement the solution - just discuss it in high details, if they aced the original question. This helps us distinguish between good candidtaes and outstanding ones

Comment: I'm trying to implement something like this right now, I'll post it as a solution and hopefully somebody comes along and finds a better one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach**

1. Find paths that spell words.  We only continue a path as long as its a prefix of a word.
2. We quickly check if a word is a prefix by using bisect_left to check if it's found in the list of words (a fast alternative to Trie Tree).
3. We gather the list of paths for each word
4. We reduce the paths to the non-overlapping ones to satisfy the requirement that no two words share a cell letter.

**Code**

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def find_words(board, words, x, y, prefix, path):
    ' Find words that can be generated starting at position x, y '
    
    # Base case
    # find if current word prefix is in list of words
    found = bisect_left(words, prefix)  # can use binary search since words are sorted
    if found >= len(words):
        return
   
    if words[found] == prefix:
        yield prefix, path              # Prefix in list of words

    # Give up on path if what we found is not even a prefix
    # (there is no point in going further)
    if len(words[found]) < len(prefix) or words[found][:len(prefix)] != prefix:
        return
    
    # Extend path by one lettter in boarde
    # Since can only go right and down 
    # No need to worry about same cell occurring multiple times in a given path
    for adj_x, adj_y in [(0, 1), (1, 0)]:
        x_new, y_new = x + adj_x, y + adj_y
        if x_new < len(board) and y_new < len(board[0]):
            yield from find_words(board, words, x_new, y_new, \
                                  prefix + board[x_new][y_new], \
                                  path + [(x_new, y_new)])
     
def check_all_starts(board, words):
    ' find all possilble paths through board for generating words '
    # check each starting point in board
    for x in range(len(board)):
        for y in range(len(board[0])):
            yield from find_words(board, words, x, y, board[x][y], [(x, y)])
   
def find_non_overlapping(choices, path):
    ' Find set of choices with non-overlapping paths '
    if not choices:
        # Base case
        yield path
    else:
        word, options = choices[0]

        for option in options:
            set_option = set(option)
            
            if any(set_option.intersection(p) for w, p in path):
                # overlaps with path
                continue
            else:
                yield from find_non_overlapping(choices[1:], path + [(word, option)])
        
    
def solve(board, words):
    ' Solve for path through board to create words '
    words.sort()
    
    # Get choice of paths for each word
    choices = {}
    for word, path in check_all_starts(board, words):
        choices.setdefault(word, []).append(path)
    
    # Find non-intersecting paths (i.e. no two words should have a x, y in common)
    if len(choices) == len(words):
        return next(find_non_overlapping(list(choices.items()), []), None)
```

**Tests**

*Test 1*

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

words = [ "dog", "dogma", "cat" ]
board = [
            ['d', 'r', 'd', 'o', 'r', 's'],
            ['o', 'b', 'i', 'g', 'n', 'c'],
            ['g', 'f', 'n', 'm', 't', 'a'],
            ['x', 's', 'i', 'a', 'n', 't']]

pp(solve(board, words))
```

*Output*

```
Test 1
[('dog', [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)]),
 ('dogma', [(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)]),
 ('cat', [(1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5)])]
```

*Test 2*

```
words = ["by","bat"] 
board = [ ['b', 'a', 't'], 
          ['y', 'x', 'b'], 
          ['x', 'x', 'y'], ] 

pp(solve(board, words))
```

*Output*

```
Test 2
[('bat', [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)]), 
 ('by', [(1, 2), (2, 2)])]
```

Comment: I think out of all the answers here, I like yours the most. It's simple and more efficient than my solution and totally doable in an interview. With a Trie, it will probably be even faster since you don't have O(log(n)) to search through a list

Comment: @AlexPeniz--thanks.  Thought using the binary search would be a neat alternative to mention during an interview since most candidates would think of the Trie.  Also, since the binary search uses a built-in Python function (thus C-code) it could be relatively fast despite the extra complexity of log(n) multiplier for the word search relative to the Trie.

Comment: @DarrylG I am not sure about sorting array of words at the beginning of `solve(board, words)`  It makes no difference for those two test cases. Your code gives the same results for words = `[ "dog", "dogma", "cat" ]` and words = `[ "dogma", "dog", "cat" ]`

Comment: @YuriGinsburg--hi Yuri.  Sorting is necessary in order to use binary search (i.e. bisect_left in this case).  Otherwise, bisect_left returns the incorrect index into the list of words.  For instance if we don't sort and `words = ['banana', 'apple', 'peach']`, and prefix = 'a', word bisect_left(words, 'a') returns index 0.  Then since words[0]=='a' is False and `words[found][:len(prefix)] != prefix` is True, we conclude that 'a' is not a valid prefix and we will never find 'apple' (i.e. words[1]).

Answer (score 2):

The task of finding the words in the grid can be done through the solutions provided in the other answers, or through tries, suffix trees or arrays.

As an example, based on the answer given by @Péter Leéh, this would be a modified version for finding all paths using `python3`:

```py
grid = [
    ['d', 'r', 'd', 'o', 'r', 's'],
    ['o', 'b', 'i', 'g', 'n', 'c'],
    ['g', 'f', 'n', 'm', 't', 'a'],
    ['x', 's', 'i', 'a', 'n', 't']
]

words1 = [ "dog", "dogma", "cat" ]

# Building the dense grid
dense_grid = {}
for row, line in enumerate(grid):
    for col, letter in enumerate(line):
        dense_grid.setdefault(letter, []).append((row, col))

# Finding all paths for all words
def is_valid_move(p, q):
    return ( p[0] == q[0] and p[1]+1 == q[1] ) or ( p[0]+1 == q[0] and p[1] == q[1] )
        
def find_all_paths(curr_pos, suffix, dense_grid=dense_grid):
    if len(suffix) == 0: 
        return [[curr_pos]]
    
    possible_suffix_paths = []
    for pos in dense_grid[suffix[0]]:
        if is_valid_move(curr_pos, pos):
            possible_suffix_paths += find_all_paths(pos, suffix[1:])

        # Since the list of positions is ordered, I can skip the rest
        elif pos[0] - curr_pos[0] >= 2:
            break
        
    return [ [curr_pos] + p for p in possible_suffix_paths ]

words_paths = [ 
    [ path for pos in dense_grid[word[0]] for path in find_all_paths(pos, word[1:]) ]
    for word in words1
]
```

The final `dense_grid` is a dictionary from character to list of positions in the grid, being the positions represented by `(row, column)`:

```
{
    'd': [(0, 0), (0, 2)],
    'r': [(0, 1), (0, 4)],
    'o': [(0, 3), (1, 0)],
    's': [(0, 5), (3, 1)],
    'b': [(1, 1)],
    'i': [(1, 2), (3, 2)],
    'g': [(1, 3), (2, 0)],
    'n': [(1, 4), (2, 2), (3, 4)],
    'c': [(1, 5)],
    'f': [(2, 1)],
    'm': [(2, 3)],
    't': [(2, 4), (3, 5)],
    'a': [(2, 5), (3, 3)],
    'x': [(3, 0)]
}
```

The final `words_paths` is a list containing for each word a list of all possible paths, being each path defined by a sequence (list) of positions in the grid:

```
[
    [
         [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)], # dog
         [(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3)]
    ],
    [
         [(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)] # dogma
    ],
    [
         [(1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5)] # cat
    ]
]
```

After you have all the possible paths for all the words, you can find the words with unique characters by transforming the problem into a [digraph maximum flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem).

To do the transformation of this problem, for every word, you have to create a starting and ending node, henceforth called `START_word` and `END_word`. The `START_word` nodes are connected to all the first positions of the paths of the word, which will then be connected to the second positions, and so on. The last positions of all the paths of the word will then be connected to the `END_word` node.
The nodes of the positions are unique across the graph. Meaning that words sharing the same positions in the grid, will also share the same nodes.

Now that we have the graph representing all the possible paths for all the words, we just need to connect a `SOURCE` node to all the starting nodes, and connect all the ending nodes to a `TARGET` node. With the resulting graph, you can the solve the maximum flow problem, where every edge in the graph as a capacity of `1`.

This would be the resulting graph that you get from the problem you defined in the question:

[image]

However, to make sure that there are no nodes where the minimum of the in degree and out degree is greater than 1, we also need to add choking nodes. Assuming that a node has this characteristic, we need to remove all the out edges, and connect the original node with a single choking node. To the choking node is then added the original node's out edges.

I tested this idea using the library [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/), and here is the code I used to test it:

```py
import networkx as nx

# Connecting source node with starting nodes
edges = [ ("SOURCE", "START_"+word) for word in words1 ]

# Connecting ending nodes with target nodes
edges += [ ("END_"+word, "TARGET") for word in words1 ]

# Connecting characters between them and to the starting and ending nodes too
edges += list(set(
    ( s_node if isinstance(s_node, tuple) else s_node, 
      t_node if isinstance(t_node, tuple) else t_node )
    for word, paths in zip(words1, words_paths)
    for path in paths
    for s_node, t_node in zip(["START_"+word] + path, path + ["END_"+word])
))

# Generating graph from the nodes and edges created
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edges_from(edges, capacity=1)

# Adding choke nodes if required
node_edge_dict = {}
nodes_indeg_gt1 = [ node for node, in_deg in g.in_degree() if not isinstance(node, str) and in_deg > 1 ]
for s_node, t_node in g.out_edges(nodes_indeg_gt1):
    node_edge_dict.setdefault(s_node, []).append(t_node)
    
for node, next_nodes in node_edge_dict.items():
    if len(next_nodes) <= 1: continue

    choke_node = node + (-1,)
    g.add_edge(node, choke_node, capacity=1)
    g.add_edges_from([ (choke_node, p) for p in next_nodes ], capacity=1)
    g.remove_edges_from([ (node, p) for p in next_nodes ])

# Solving the maximum flow problem
num_words, max_flow_dict = nx.algorithms.flow.maximum_flow(g, "SOURCE", "TARGET")

# Extracting final paths for all the words
final_words_path = []
for word in words1:
    word_path = []
    start = "START_"+word
    end = "END_"+word
    node = start
    
    while node != end:
        node = next( n for n,f in max_flow_dict[node].items() if f == 1 )
        if isinstance(node, str) or len(node) == 3: continue
        word_path.append(node)
    
    final_words_path.append(word_path)
    
print(final_words_path)
```

The output for the problem stated in the question is this:

```
[
    [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)], # dog
    [(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)], # dogma
    [(1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5)] # cat
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at a solution. First, I find all possible paths that I can take to spell any of the words. Paths are indexed by the word that they spell. Then I iterate through all possible combinations of paths by adding one possible path per word at a time while maintaining a seen set. Once I run out of feasible paths for a word before I find them all, then I backtrack.

```
def findWords(grid, words):
    # Regular old dfs through the grid, we only go right or down
    def dfs(row, col, path, idx):
        if idx == len(word):
            if word in all_paths:
                all_paths[word].append(list(path))
            else:
                all_paths[word] = [list(path)]
        else:
            if row + 1 < len(grid):
                if grid[row+1][col] == word[idx]:
                    path.append((row+1, col))
                    dfs(row+1, col, path, idx+1)
                    path.pop()
            if col + 1 < len(grid[0]):
                if grid[row][col+1] == word[idx]:
                    path.append((row, col+1))
                    dfs(row, col+1, path, idx+1)
                    path.pop()

    # For each word, find all possible paths through the grid to spell the word
    # Each path is a collection of coordinates as is desired from the function
    # Paths are indexed by word and stored in a list in a dictionary
    all_paths = {}
    for row in range(len(grid)):
        for col in range(len(grid[0])):
            for word in words:
                if grid[row][col] == word[0]:
                    dfs(row, col, [(row, col)], 1)

    # Try all possible combinations of paths from each letter
    def dfs2(idx):
        if idx == len(words):
            return True

        word = words[idx]
        for path in all_paths[word]:
            for loc in path:
                if loc in seen:
                    return False
            for loc in path:
                seen.add(loc)
            if dfs2(idx+1):
                retlst.append(path)
                return True
            else:
                for loc in path:
                    seen.remove(loc)
        return False

    # Backtrack through possible combinations
    seen = set([])
    retlst = []
    dfs2(0)
    return retlst
```

There's probably a way to DFS through possible combinations of paths WHILE you're DFSing through the words you need to spell to avoid pre-computing all paths, but it was way too complicated for me to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31687454/11751294) answer, first you want to make a dictionary which maps letter to positions:

```py
board = [
    ['d', 'r', 'd', 'o', 'r', 's'],
    ['o', 'b', 'i', 'g', 'n', 'c'],
    ['g', 'f', 'n', 'm', 't', 'a'],
    ['x', 's', 'i', 'a', 'n', 't']
]

words = [ "dog", "dogma", "cat" ]

letter_positions = {}
for y, row in enumerate(board):
    for x, letter in enumerate(row):
         letter_positions.setdefault(letter, []).append((x, y))
```

```py
>>> letter_positions
{'d': [(0, 0), (2, 0)],
 'r': [(1, 0), (4, 0)],
 'o': [(3, 0), (0, 1)],
 's': [(5, 0), (1, 3)],
 'b': [(1, 1)],
 'i': [(2, 1), (2, 3)],
 'g': [(3, 1), (0, 2)],
 'n': [(4, 1), (2, 2), (4, 3)],
 'c': [(5, 1)],
 'f': [(1, 2)],
 'm': [(3, 2)],
 't': [(4, 2), (5, 3)],
 'a': [(5, 2), (3, 3)],
 'x': [(0, 3)]}
```

As in the linked answer, you should keep track of valid moves. Also you can only move down or right, so I added a plus condition compared to the original answer. I left the `find_word` function unchanged.

```py
def is_valid_move(position, last):
    if last == []:
        return True
    if position[0] < last[0] or position[1] < last[1]: 
        return False # only allow down and right
    return (
        abs(position[0] - last[0]) <= 1 and
        abs(position[1] - last[1]) <= 1
    )

def find_word(word, used=None):
    if word == "":
        return []
    if used is None:
        used = []
    letter, rest = word[:1], word[1:]
    for position in letter_positions.get(letter) or []:
        if position in used:
            continue
        if not is_valid_move(position, used and used[-1]):
            continue
        path = find_word(rest, used + [position])
        if path is not None:
            return [position] + path
    return None
```

A little bit of explanation of the logic of `find_word`. The idea here is to take the first letter of the word in `letter` and store every other letter in `rest`, then iterate over the possible positions of that letter. Filter those positions based on if it's used and if it's a valid move. After that, recursively call `find_word` on the rest of the letters.

```py
for word in words:
    print(find_word(word))
```

```py
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)] # dog
[(2, 0), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)] # dogma
[(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)] # cat
```

Well, the indexing is flipped compared to the question, but that shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: I tried your code on this example:
```
board = [
    ['b', 'a', 't'],
    ['y', 'x', 'b'],
    ['x', 'x', 'y'],
]

words = ["by","bat"]
```
but i got an overlap of the "b" characters in "by" and "bat"

Comment: @AlexPeniz Yes, because `used` needs to be stored across words too.

Comment: @AlexPeniz The easiest would be just to store found words in a list, then modify `is_valid_move` to return `False` for them.

Comment: I'm still a little confused how this avoids the overlapping letters problem, though. Suppose we take the bat/by example I have above. In the for loop, suppose "by" comes before "bat" and we find (0,0), (1,0). In this case, we return [(0,0), (1,0)], we'll mark both of those coordinates as used, and move onto bat. Only this time, there are no remaining moves for bat. I think the problem you listed was more for a game: given the grid, you want to find a word using the remaining letters. In this case, we want ALL the words, not just the ones we could get after each turn.

Comment: @AlexPeniz Well, the order of the words does matter. If you run in with `"words = ["bat", "by"]"`, it works. I agree that this is a weak point.

Comment: I do believe the "next move" method of representing the board and searching that way may be much faster though, I'll try incorporating that into my solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it:

```
def sol(word, board):
    rows = len(board)
    cols = len(board[0])
    coordinates = []
    wordCnt = 0
    co = []
    result = []
    def getWord(row, col, word, wordCnt, board):
        if row < 0 or col < 0 or row > len(board)-1 or col > len(board[0])-1 or wordCnt > len(word) -1 or board[row][col] != word[wordCnt]:
            return
        result.append(word[wordCnt])
        co.append((row, col))
        getWord(row+1, col, word, wordCnt+1, board)
        getWord(row, col+1, word, wordCnt+1, board)
        return co, result

    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            if board[row][col] == word[wordCnt]:
                co, result = getWord(row, col, word, wordCnt, board)
                if ''.join(result[-len(word):]) == word:
                    print(co[-len(word):])

                
sol('cat', board)
```